# Python: How to sort and organize dictionary data

Tags: python, performance, list, csv, dictionary

I am trying to sort my crime totals by zipcode and victim count by offense type. I have built out the dictionary by report number. Here is my output of a small sample of data when I print the dictionary:

```
{'100065070': ['64130', '18', 'VIC', 'VIC', 'VIC'], '20003319': ['64130', '13', 'VIC'], '60077156': ['64130', '18', 'VIC'], '100057708': ['99999', '17', 'VIC', 'VIC'], '40024161': ['64108', '17', 'VIC', 'VIC']}
```

The dictionary is built as follows: {Report_number: [Zipcode, offense type, number of victims]}

I'm brand new to coding and am just learning dictionaries. How would I go about sorting through the dictionary to organize my data into this format?

```
 Zip Codes Crime totals
```

====================

```
   64126 809
   64127 3983

   64128 1749
   64129 1037
   64130 4718
   64131 2080
   64132 2060
   64133 2005
   64134 2928
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my code so far. I'm accessing two files with about 50,000 rows of data, so efficiency is very important.

```
from collections import Counter

incidents_f =  open('incidents.csv', mode = "r")

crime_dict = dict()

for line in incidents_f:
    line_1st = line.strip().split(",")
    if line_1st[0].upper() != "REPORT_NO":
        report_no = line_1st[0]
        offense = line_1st[3]
        zip_code = line_1st[4]
        if len(zip_code) < 5:
            zip_code = "99999"

        if report_no in crime_dict:
            crime_dict[report_no].append(zip_code).append(offense)
        else:
            crime_dict[report_no] = [zip_code]+[offense]

#close File
incidents_f.close

details_f = open('details.csv',mode = 'r')
for line in details_f:
    line_1st = line.strip().split(",")
    if line_1st[0].upper() != "REPORT_NO":
        report_no = line_1st[0]
        involvement = line_1st[1]
        if involvement.upper() == 'VIC':
            victims = "VIC"

        if report_no in crime_dict:
            crime_dict[report_no].append(victims)
        else:
            continue


#close File
details_f.close



print(crime_dict)
```

Comment: It would help if you could edit the question to include a couple of sample lines from your CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it with more code than @Alexander's solution:

```
crime_dict ={
    '100065070': ['64130', '18', 'VIC', 'VIC', 'VIC'], 
    '20003319': ['64130', '13', 'VIC'], 
    '60077156': ['64130', '18', 'VIC'],
    '100057708': ['99999', '17', 'VIC', 'VIC'], 
    '40024161': ['64108', '17', 'VIC', 'VIC']
    }

crimes_by_zip = {}
for k, v in crime_dict.items():
    zip = v[0]
    if zip not in crimes_by_zip.keys():
        crimes_by_zip[zip] = 0
    crimes_by_zip[zip] += 1

for zip in sorted(crimes_by_zip.keys()):
    print(zip, crimes_by_zip[zip])

64108 1
64130 3
99999 1
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. This worked perfectly and makes complete sense. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
D = {'100065070': ['64130', '18', 'VIC', 'VIC', 'VIC'], '20003319': ['64130', '13', 'VIC'], '60077156': ['64130', '18', 'VIC'], '100057708': ['99999', '17', 'VIC', 'VIC'], '40024161': ['64108', '17', 'VIC', 'VIC']}

data_with_zip_duplicate = [(D[key][0],key) for  key in sorted(D.keys(), key = lambda x:D[x][0] )]
print(*data_with_zip_duplicate, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. We have not gotten to Lambda functions just yet, but I have seen those solutions everywhere when looking up this question. I am curious, is the lambda function more efficient than the zip solution Steve suggested?